# Facebook omniauth gem doesn't work on remote domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ssl, omniauth

I'm using omniauth-facebook to allow users to login through Facebook on my rails app.

My site is SSL, and the authentication works perfectly in a local environment, but in production I get the following error: "Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://"

I see a lot of similar questions but none of the solutions there work, so I resort to asking. Can anyone help?

Comment: what is your redirect url in facebook app config.

Comment: I put https:// example.com redirect url is (no space of course)

Comment: It seems that the "Enforce HTTPS" checkbox is enabled by default in you app settings.

Comment: It is enabled, and I am unable to change it, but also my site is using https. Why would that box being checked cause a problem?

Comment: check this https://github.com/daroczig/fbRads/issues/85

Comment: thanks for that. I checked it out and though the issue is similar, we are not trying to do the same thing and it is in a different language. I'm not sure it can be considered the same error. Either way, that issue has not been resolved

Comment: And what is the value of the redirect_uri parameter in your actual login dialog call? (Check browser address bar.)

Comment: It's https:// example.com/auth/facebook  I've changed the url to that too and it doesn't work